# Does SQL Server 2016 still contain sqlmaint.exe?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-tools

According to the documentation ([Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016)), `sqlmaint.exe` should still be available (emphasis mine):

> This topic describes the deprecated SQL Server Database Engine features that are **still available in SQL Server 2016**. These features are **scheduled to be removed in a future release** of SQL Server.
>
> ...
>
> Tools: sqlmaint Utility ...

It is definitely *not listed* on the [list of discontinued features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/discontinued-database-engine-functionality-in-sql-server-2016).

However, I fail to find `sqlmaint.exe` on my recently installed SQL Server 2016 Express systems. In previous versions, it was in the same folder as `sqlserver.exe`.

Is the documentation wrong? Or did the file location move? Or did I miss something during the install process?

*(Note: Encouraged by the comments reproducing this issue, I have created a [Microsoft Connect entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3139260/sqlmaint-exe-missing-in-sql-server-2016) for this, which was migrated to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32898298-sqlmaint-exe-missing-in-sql-server-2016).)*

Comment: Speculation: could also be because of Express edition?

Comment: @BradC: Up until at least SQL Server 2012 (don't have 2014 installed right now), sqlmaint.exe was included in the Express edition. In fact, it's the only built-in way to automate rotating backups on Express editions (which do not include SQL Server Agent).

Comment: I am looking at enterprise edition. It is not in `E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn` there anymore.

Comment: [Deprecated Database Engine Features in SQL Server 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016) document is confusing, see the comments at the end of the document.  I assume this is discontinued.

Comment: I have a newly installed Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU3) (KB4019916) - 13.0.4435.0 (X64)   Apr 27 2017 17:36:12   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit). And i can confirm that its not installed with that version.

Comment: FWIW, I do see it in my SQL Server 2014 Express folder: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\Binn\sqlmaint.exe"`, but not in my 2016 Express or Developer folders.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft documentation mentions they're removing it, it says "Next Version" but i assume this was written for a previous version. They advise to use maintenance plans in the future.

[Microsoft Documentation for sqlmaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlmaint-utility)

Edit: Last update on that article was 03/14/2017. But given all the examples point to it being originally written with SQL Server 2008 in some and edited with later versions as examples (it's all over the place to be honest), it's probably safe to say the note at the top is wrong and it's actually removed already.